# Win Svr 2008 R2 - first instance of Windows Explorer opening selected folders in new windows

Tags: windows, 64-bit

Well it looks like a question related to this was asked and then closed in 2010, but it is a new problem with running my server so I'm going to ask it again.

I cannot remember the exact time it started, but during the past 2 months Windows Explorer has been opening folders in new windows - from the first instance only - even though I have quadruple-checked the settings, and they are set to open in the same window.

After I click a folder or drive, the next Explorer window that opens behaves as expected, but the first instance of Explorer always does this annoying-as-hell behavior.

I've seen this problem cropping up intermittently according to Google since 2007, but I'm not inclined to go screwing with my registry if I didn't do anything there in the first place - and I didn't.

I generally install all critical Windows Updates once a month and none of the optional ones. 
So, is there any help out there for this?

THANKS
sF

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that this was caused by an update to IE8, so I installed IE9 and the issue went away!